# Getting back to base url in require function in PHP

Tags: php, path, require

How do you get the base url when calling the require function for PHP?

My file is located in :

```
www.mywebsite.com/folder_1/file.php
```

in my server it's placed in:

```
/folder_1/file.php
```

I want to get to the file using the PHP require function but I can't seem to get there.

I have already tried :

```
require 'http://www.mywebsite.com/folder_1/file.php';
```

and

require '../folder_1/file.php';

My View (where I placed the require function) is located in

```
/application/innerdirectory/another_innerdirectory/another_dir/view_directory/view.php
```

What's the correct path for my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
require_once(__DIR__."/folder_1/file.php");
```

or

```
include(__DIR__."/folder_1/file.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for this:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'folder_1/file.php';
```

And remember, require works from server side, so you don't expect great results, when trying to include a `http://` file.